# Too many values to unpack in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Battleship game but I'm stuck at the ship generation.
When I'm trying to run this:

#### Initialization

```
print "Welcome to Battleships!!!"
board = []
import os
from random import randint

for x in range(10):
    board.append(["O"] * 10)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " | ".join(row)

ships = {"battleship" : [5], "cruiser1" : [4], "cruiser2" : [4], "frigate1" : [3], "frigate2" : [3], "frigate3" : [3], "frigate4" : [3], "minesweeper1" : [2], "minesweeper2" : [2], "minesweeper3" : [2], "minesweeper4" : [2]}
numbers1 = []
numbers2 = []
numbers = []
```

#### Some Setup Functions

```
def setup_nums1():
    for count1 in range(6):
        for count2 in range(10):
            number1 = (count1)*100
            number2 = count2
            numbers1.append(number1 + number2)
def setup_nums2():
    for count1 in range(10):
        for count2 in range(6):
            number1 = (count1)*100
            number2 = count2
            numbers2.append(number1 + number2)
def setup_nums():
    for count1 in range(10):
        for count2 in range(10):
            number1 = (count1)*100
            number2 = count2
            numbers.append(number1 + number2)
def setup_numbers():
    setup_nums()
    setup_nums1()
    setup_nums2()
def setup_ships(): 
    x = 59 
    for ship, info in ships:
        direction = randint(1,2)
        if direction == 1:
            ships[ship].append(numbers1[randint (0,x)])
            y = info[1]
            print y
            numbers1.remove(y)
            if y in numbers2:
                numbers2.remove(y)
            numbers.remove(y)
            x = x - 1
            for n in range(ship[0]):
                ships[ship].append(y + n  + 1)
                numbers1.remove(y + n + 1)
                if (y + n + 1) in numbers2:
                    numbers2.remove(y + n + 1)
                numbers.remove(y + n + 1)
                x = x - 1                
        if direction == 2:
            ships[ship].append(numbers2[randint (0,x)])
            y = info[1]
            print y
            numbers2.remove(y)
            if y in numbers1:
                numbers1.remove(y)
            numbers.remove(y)
            x = x - 1
            for n in range(ship[0]):
                ships[ship].append(y + n*100  + 100)
                numbers2.remove(y + n*100 + 100)
                if (y + n + 1) in numbers1:
                    numbers1.remove(y + n*100 + 100)
                numbers.remove(y + n*100 + 100)  
                x = x - 1
```

### Main program

```
setup_nums1()
setup_nums2()
setup_ships()
print numbers1
print numbers2
print ships
```

I get this error:

```
Welcome to Battleships!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthew/Documents/battleship2.py", line 77, in <module>
    setup_ships()
  File "/home/matthew/Documents/battleship2.py", line 41, in setup_ships
    for ship, info in ships:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many values to unpack means that the function you are calling returns several values and you are only taking care of some of these values.

problem is in

```
for ship, info in ships:
```

this must be like

```
for ship, info in ships.items():
```

**OR**

```
for ship, info in ships.iteritems():
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `for ship, info in ships` try `for ship, info in ships.iteritems()`.

Using the `in ships` syntax, you are only able to return one value (they key).

For example, you could do:

```
ships = { 'a': 'ship_a', 'b': 'ship_b', 'c': 'ship_c' }
for key in ships:
    print(key) # Outputs a b c
```

Instead, if you do:

```
for key, value in ships.iteritems():
    print(key, value) # Outputs ('a', 'ship_a') ('b', 'ship_b') ('c': 'ship_c')
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/1924026) for more information about Python 2.x and Python 3.x compatibility.